# How to make styles not to modify external packages styles?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

Example:
`main.scss` that exists on every page declares a default style for button:

```
button {
   box-shadow: ...;
   border-radius: ...;
}
```

And then when I use any package from npmjs, buttons from them are broken. What are the best practices?

My thoughts:

- Do not use global styles. Style button on every page separately.
- Create component with custom classname (for example `appname-button`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve your problem pick one:

- Use custom, prefixed classes:

```css
.app-btn {}
```

Class selector has more weight than tag selector, so your stiles will be applied. Using prefix (app) guarantees that you will not mess with other class selectors.

- If you are using React you can [use css modules](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-a-css-modules-stylesheet/)

This approach requires some setup, however allow you to use the same selectors without any worries.

Cons of using CSS Modules:

- Setup is a bit harder then pure css (minor)
- CSS bundle slightly bigger because of using hashes (minor)
- You will not be able to reference elements via className because it will be dynamic. Means that you may experience some difficulties with test, but this can be solved using the test-id tag (medium)

Comment: What are cons of using `css modules`? For example how many problems will it cause when parsing?

Comment: @FreePhoenix I am working with them for something like 2 years. From my point of view there are only 3 cons: 
* Setup is a bit harder then pure css (minor)
* CSS bundle slightly bigger because of using hashes (minor)
*  You will not be able to reference elements via className because it will be dynamic. Means that you may experience some difficulties with test, but this can be solved using the test-id tag (medium)
That's it

Answer (score 1):

There are quite few ways to handle this. But what is the best depends on the need of your project and your teams preference.
Ideally, each your component should have it's own set of styles, separated from global scope. So, you have some sample folder structure

```
components
 - Button
   -- Button.js or Button.tsx
   -- button.css
   -- Button.test.js or Button.test.tsx
```

E.g. if you are using atomic design, you might start development from simple atoms (such as button, input, etc.), and each atom contains it's own set of styles.
There are at least few approaches to look at:

1. Use styled-components: https://github.com/styled-components/styled-components
2. Use CSS modules
3. Use one of many other solutions (e.g. https://github.com/kof/react-jss, https://emotion.sh/docs/introduction, etc.) There are quite a lot of them, depends on what are you looking for.

Answer (score 0):

change:

```
button {
box-shadow: ...;
border-radius: ...;
}
```

to:

```
button2 {
box-shadow: ...;
border-radius: ...;
}
```

or any name you want and call it anywhere you want